Can someone help identify a cop film about the devil?
I remember seeing a movie on TV around around 2011, and I've been wondering what it was called out of curiosity, and I can't seem to find it. 
From what I remember, the protagonist was a cop/detective, investigating murders that the devil committed (not knowing it was the devil until later), he also had a beard. 
The devil in the film had possessed the body of someone, and only possesses him throughout the film, until the ending. In the film his goal is to get this girl to complete a ritual, if I remember correctly to have sex with her (there's no nudity in the film at all). The devil is also blind when he enters the church, and at one point when he enters the church he kills a priest by stabbing his forehead with a cross. 
The ending of the film includes a final battle that takes place on a running subway as the protagonist and the girl try to escape the devil, they escape the subway and they run to a church while the entire town/city is brainwashed by the devil. The protagonist is prepared to fight the spirit of the devil (as the body the devil possessed was destroyed on the subway), but when he looks around the church, he drops his weapon, only for the devil to possess him. As he's (while possessed) dragging the girl to the middle of the room, the protagonist gains control at the last minute, and impales himself onto something sharp, killing himself while defeating the devil, and then the movie ends as the girl cries over the sacrifice of the protagonist.
The character also has a friend of his, which is killed at one point, but brought back from the devil and brainwashed. However when the protagonist is caught, and the friend is ordered to kill the protagonist, he can't bring himself to do it, as a result he's killed by the devil (I think he was set on fire). 
The presentation was also darkly lit, like Man of Steel, but not from the same director (trust me, I've checked). The genre was horror and thriller. 
Any help would be appreciated. 

This is End of Days with Arnold Schwarzenegger from 1999.

On December 28th, 1999, the citizens of New York City are getting ready for the turn of the millennium. However, the Devil decides to crash the party by coming to the city, inhabiting a man's body, and searching for his chosen bride, a 20-year-old woman named Christine York. If he bears her child between 11:00 PM and midnight on New Year's Eve, the world will end, and the only hope lies within an atheist ex-cop named Jericho Cane, who no longer believes in God because of the murder of his wife and daughter. 

All the scenes you described are there and you can see some of them in the trailer:




Yeah, that's the movie I was looking for, I didn't even realize Arnold was in it. O_O Thanks a lot. :D

I can see why you'd forget, BTW. It's almost 20 years old and not considered one of Arnold's best.
